# Type-Safe-Builder eval in Kotlin Native

Tags: kotlin, dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am experimenting a bit with [Type Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) in Kotlin. Now I have gotten the HML example to output by using the following.

```
val dsl = File("example.kts").readText()

val manager = ScriptEngineManager()
val engine = manager.getEngineByExtension("kts")

val html = engine.eval(dsl).toString()
```

Is this the right approach at all for running this from Kotlin?

If so, is there a way to make this work in Kotlin Multiplatform/Native, specifically when combining with Objective-C? (The ScriptEngine comes from a JVM dependency).

If not, what is the right way?

Comment: Kotlin/Native does not provide C++ interoperability.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Updated to Objective-C for more clarity as it is a combination of both